# why python dependencies are not installing?

Tags: amazon-ec2, sh, github-actions, aws-code-deploy, cicd

i was trying to create a ci-cd workflow from github-actions to ec2. but a part of the workflow is not working. there is a part where we can install the python dependencies using a shell file. but there is a problem while accessing requirements.txt . please help me out.

this is my shell script:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
cd /home/ec2-user/app/Phalguna
virtualenv environment
source environment/bin/activate
sudo pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

and this is my error: `ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'`

Comment: Please paste the relevant YAML along with logs directly into the question rather than linking it.

Comment: @rethab please review the question once again.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the first sentence here:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/

> "Output installed packages in requirements format."

You have just created a new virtual environment with no installed packages. So pip freeze, of course, cannot possibly output any dependency of your application. You have to do it from your testing environment with all the packages already installed and ship it with the rest of your application.